# Api with high compute requirements written in Node.js

Tags: node.js, performance, ubuntu-14.04

we are running an api on a 12 cores server with a high performance ssd. The app is run using pm2 cluster mode (--i 0). The problem i am facing is that we are using the api to do calculations, which for instance spans over 40 years along with 12 months of each year. 
In some situations i have to run them in parallel. when i run 5 tasks in parallel using async.parallel, one core is captured for 10 seconds. According to those stats we can assume that if one core is busy at 100% usage for 10 seconds, a server with 12 cores is going to server 12 concurrent requests from users.
My question is should we be using node.js for this purpose? or is there a better way or a recommended way to handle this kind of a situation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems unrelated to `node.js`. You would have this problem regardless of programming language. Your problems are more related to your design. It seems to me you need some form of caching mechanism, so future requests don't need to take 10 seconds each. You could also do the computing ahead of time and store the results in a database.

Comment: Yes i have tried that approach. The only problem is every request for analysis is going to be a different set of data. I wanted to know that is node.js built to do this kind of work because i have read in different blog posts that using a strictly typed compiled language should be faster (although I have my doubts about that).

Comment: Well, you can always write the processing parts in another language, e.g. c or something else, if you're worried about performance.